# Multiple dashes in URL causes 404

Tags: http, url, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Currently i'm rewriteting my titles to slug. But when i make a slug from a sentence with a dash in it. The dash is included in the slug.

So this `Awesome Title - 2017` get's converted to the slug `awesome-title---2017`

I know it's a quick fix, but i was wondering why it's not a valid URL as it throws a 404 page.

Maybe it's related to the backbone history routing implementation,. which is implemented in the single-page-app.

The thing I can't explain, is that I use the slugs for the routing config, so it's feed with the url with the three dashes (`http://website.com/fake-url---with-extra-dashes`), but when going to the url it gives and 404 error, while the one without dashes (`http://website.com/fake-url-with-extra-dashes`) is working.

Are there some kind of automatic rewriting going on behind the scene in Backbone? or is the browser rewriting the url, because multiple dashes is invalid?

Comment: Don't you think you need to escape the actual dash (`Awesome Title - 2017`) somehow to not be interpreted as a space regardless of the routing mechanism you're using?

Comment: Yes. i think so. But i'm still wondering why it isn't a valid URL.